# ATI Radeon X600 and two monitors

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, radeon

just installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS, can not customize as expected two monitors in any attempt to change the parameters of their joint work- error, and indeed the system slows down, I think it's because of the video card drivers, How can this be solved?

Comment: are you using fglrx or cypress driver?

Comment: I dont know, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to amd.com to find the driver for your exact card. After downloading, extract the package and find the amd....sh inside the folder. Right click on it, select "Allow executing file as program" and then double click the file. If you are 14.04 then select the generate distro option. If you have an older version then select the install on x.org6.9+. After isnztallation reboot and then use the Catalyst Control Center to configure the monitor.